How to send user information through an email to it support department
I am working on a ticketing system project in django i have made the front end pages, so in first page their is a form which takes user details as input so when user add their Details in that form then I want that the details is sent through the Email to it support department of our company. How this process could be proceed ?
I don't try yet ,I just want to know the process

I think a small search should be done before asking, you should try then ask,  the process is so easy, just search django doc.  for sending emails.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/email/
